# GET file:///dist/build.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue project and when I view the file index.html I get a blank page and when I go to the browser console I see the error

```
GET file:///dist/build.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This is in my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import Jumbotron from './Jumbotron.vue'
Vue.component('jumbotron', Jumbotron)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
  //router: router
})
```

And this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vuejs-blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Vue` with `.vue` file components - you need to run a web server with `webpack`.  If you created this project using `vue-cli` you can just run `npm run serve` from the command line. Otherwise you have to write a `webpack` config, in order to transpile your code into something a browser can understand.

[This was my first project I ever built with `Vue`](https://github.com/oze4/v-ipmapper) - it uses multiple files that utilize template literals.. It may help point you in the right direction if you're interested in learning `Vue` without having to mess around with `webpack`, etc.. (like I wanted to do a first)

You cannot load `.vue` files as you are attempting, and you cannot load module files over the `file://` protocol - you need a web server for this 'advanced' style of code.

***If you want to be able to open an `.html` file that contains `Vue` code - you have to use [`template literals`](https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d)for this.. That article outlines 7 different ways you can build `Vue` components - entry #2 outlines how to use `template literals`.***

If you save the following code to an `.html` file and then double click it - it will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">
        <!-- html will be auto injected -->
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#root',
            template: `
            <div>
                <h1>{{ myHeader }}</h1>
                <p>{{ myMessage }}</p>
            </div>
            `,
            data: {
                myHeader: "Welcome!",
                myMessage: 'Built using template literal',  
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Matt's right with his solution, but what also worked for me was to run

```
npm run dev
```

from the terminal